# How do I reset axis 1 in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I want to reset my column headers in pandas.  I want my column names to be my top row and then my column headers to be reset to 0,1,2,3 in pandas dataframe.  How do i perform this operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one-liner

```
df.T.reset_index().T
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column header names with .columns property of pandas dataframe.
To reset it to 0,1,2,3.. use the following code

```
>>> df.columns = list(range(len(df.columns)))
```